# replace any matching content in DOM

Tags: jquery, html, regex, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to replace every matching result on the entire html body. For example there could be divs, inputs with placeholders, data attributes where its content should be replaced. Every string that needs to be replaced could be found by its syntax

```
<div>{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}</div>
<input name="checker" placeholder="{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}" />
```

so every string that needs to be replaced could be found by regex using `/({{lc__lng_)/g` but how may I find it and then replace it?

Comment: I can't find working solution how to wrap all DOM and search for its matching results. I tried `$('body').html().match(/({{lc__lng_)/g).each(function(value){ .. });` but its not working

Comment: you are taking it wrong as I don't need just to find it. I know how to find it but I can't figure out how to replace it later. Also I'm searching for results where the strings begins with my regex `/({{lc__lng_)/g` but also I need to replace complete string not only the one I found. Thats the question I've asked - how to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where it's safe to use regex on HTML, because you're looking for easily identifiable tokens that have little chance of accidental matches with other parts of the HTML.  There is a catch, however: after manipulating the HTML as a string, you need to re-insert that string into the DOM, replacing what was there originally; this will destroy any event or data bindings that may have already been made to that HTML, and may cause issues if the page includes `<script>` tags.  This will also cause a reflow of the page.  If these would be problems in your situation, you'll need to either perform the regex replacements *before* the html is placed in the DOM, or use DOM traversal methods instead of regex.

Here's the quick-and-dirty regex method:

```js
var foo = $('#container').html();
foo = foo.replace(/{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}/g,"Header text");
foo = foo.replace(/{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}/g,"Placeholder text");
$('#container').html(foo)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div>{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}</div>
<input name="checker" placeholder="{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}" />
</div>
```

DOM traversal methods will let you replace only the parts of the DOM that you actually need to replace, preserving the rest of the page as is. How to do this will depend on exactly where these tokens appear in the DOM -- if the tokens to be replaced are in predictable locations this will be a lot easier than if they can appear at arbitrary points in the HTML.

Here I'm making the assumption that the `{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}` will always be the only thing in its node, and that the `{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}` will always be the placeholder attribute on an input field; you'll need to adjust these queries depending on your real HTML structure.  The more specific these can be, the better: if possible, use consistent classnames for each type of element you want to match, or IDs for unique elements, instead of depending on relatively slow queries like `contains()`.

```js
$('div:contains("{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}")').text("Box Header");
$('input[placeholder="{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}"]').attr("placeholder", "Placeholder text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>{{lc__lng_chat_box_header}}</div>
<input name="checker" placeholder="{{lc__lng_chat_box_input_placeholder}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution worked great and very helpful explanation about event bindings, since the `innerHtml` tag was my only option which was destroying all event binders.